# foreach() для enum

Tags: c#

Подскажите, как организовать `foreach()` для элементов `enum`?
Пример того, что хочу сделать:

```
public enum Fruits
{
        Apple,
        Orange,
        Kivi
}

public void EnumerateAllFruits()
{
        foreach (Fruits fruit in Fruits)
        {
                DoSomething(fruit);
        }
}
```

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105372/how-do-i-enumerate-an-enum

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Если именно `foreach()`, то:

```
foreach (Fruits fruit in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Fruits)))
{
     DoSomething(fruit);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если мощность перечисления известна (а она, разумеется, известна - главное, не забывать подправлять константу при изменении перечисления), то можно, например, так:

```
const int FruitsCount = 3;

public void EnumerateAllFruits()
{           
        for (Fruits fruit = 0; (int) fruit < FruitsCount; fruit++)
        {
                DoSomething(fruit);
        }
}
```

Это сработает, потому как по умолчанию элементам перечисления соответствуют целые числа от 0 до N-1 (если продолжите операцию fruit++, обнаружите, что никакой ошибки не произойдет, а fruit начнёт принимать неименованные значения 3, 4, ... )

Comment: Вы неверно поняли задачу, с помощью for() это делать не требуется, интересует именно foreach()

Comment: А если значения енумераторов 1, 2, 4, 8?..

Comment: Вы утверждаете, что такие значения могут появиться по умолчанию? Полагаю, что это не так. В данном примере значения будут такие, как я написал.

Comment: Нет, я подобного не утверждаю, я говорю что если задавать значения не по умолчанию, то этот вариант работать не будет, да и вообще он скорее похож на костыль...

Comment: Безусловно, если задавать не по умолчанию, то не будет - с этим никто не спорит. Этот вариант действительно гораздо менее красив и универсален, чем другой вариант, который я привел, но, вероятно, этот будет работать чуточку быстрее. Этот вариант оставил просто для полноты картины.

Comment: оба варианта надо было в один ответ запихать