# Enum to string помогите

Tags: c#

```
var profile = new UserInfo {NetUser = netUser, Flags = UserInfo.FlagList.Normal};
profile.SetFlag(UserInfo.FlagList.Online);

public void SetFlag(FlagList flag, bool state = true) { Flags = (state) ? Flags |= flag : Flags &= ~flag; }
```

Как мне перечисленные Enum-ы вывести как текст (Enum-ы в данном случае FlagList )?

Если через profile.Flags.ToString() то он возращает только последний - Online

```
public class UserInfo
    {
        [Flags]
        public enum FlagList
        {
            Normal,
            Online,
        }

        public FlagList Flags;

        public void SetFlag(FlagList flag, bool state = true) { Flags = (state) ? Flags |= flag : Flags &= ~flag; }
        public bool HasFlag(FlagList flag) { return (Flags & flag) == flag; }
        public void ToggleFlag(FlagList flag) { Flags ^= flag; }
    }
```

Comment: покажи определение FlagList

Comment: Прям сбоку в "Похожих" есть [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/12401/220553). Не устраивает?

Comment: @Grundy Добавил в вопрос

Comment: @EvgeniyZ не содержит открытого определения Flags

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключается в том, что по умолчанию значение для Normal - 0.

То есть, ты не можешь определить установлен этот флаг или нет. Поэтому кажется что ты установил только второй, которому присвоено следующее значение 1.

При работе с флагами лучше явно задавать каждое значение:

```
[Flags]
public enum FlagList
{
    Normal = 1,
    Online = 1<<1,
    // и т.д.
}
```

В этом случае сработает переопределенный `ToString` и после кода в вопросе выведется `Normal, Online`

Comment: большое спасибо